# How, from code, can I access controls that were created by a DataTemplate within an ItemControls ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, datatemplate

To reproduce make certain to include the `System.Windows.Interactivity` reference.

Given the following -

```
<Window
    x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Example" mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Static l:App.ItemsSource}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <l:PanelObserver />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

backed by the following classes -

```
public partial class App : Application {
    private static readonly string[] _itemsSource = new string[]{
        "This", "Is", "An", "Example"
    };

    public static string[ ] ItemsSource => _itemsSource;
}

public class PanelObserver : Behavior<Panel> {
    protected override void OnAttached( ) {
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler( _Loaded );
        void _Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
            UIElementCollection children = ( sender as Panel )?.Children;
            //So how can I resolve the children ( which is many ContentPresenters )
            //into text blocks?
        }
    }
}
```

Within the behaviors `OnAttached` method, the `Loaded` event handler is called when the control is loaded.

The `UIElementCollection` contains a number of `ContentPresenter` objects...

How/When can/do I access the `TextBlock` objects that should be contained within the `UniformGrid`?

Comment: Write a recursive method using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()`/`VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()`. If you search Stack Overflow you'll probably find a few examples you can borrow.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - No. This results in the same as UIElementCollection - a bunch of ContentPresenters.

Comment: And the ContentPresenters have no visual children? For each item in the ItemsControl, a ContentPresenter is created *which contains the content for that item*. That's why UIElementCollection contains ContentPresenters: They present the content.

Comment: Let me try this again. I've used that method in the past but it did not resolve the controls properly. I will post the results...

Comment: This works but there is another problem that goes beyond the scope of this question. Thanks.